# add new column with different results values to each row

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to add new column with a resulting values of a loop and assign these values to each new cell of each row but i keep getting the result of last row in all cells of that new column.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from os.path import dirname, join, pardir, realpath
import sys
sys.path.append(realpath(join(dirname(__file__), pardir, pardir)))
import pandas as pan
from mrz.generator.td1 import TD1CodeGenerator


data = pan.read_csv('test.csv')

df = pan.DataFrame(data)

    #TD1CodeGenerator(row)


for index, col in df.iterrows():
    Barcode=TD1CodeGenerator(str(col['Document type']), str(col['Country']), str(col['Document number']), str(col['Birth date']), str(col['Genre']), str(col['Expiry Date']), str(col['Nationality']), str(col['Surname']), str(col['Given name(s)']), str(col['Optional data 1']))

for i in df.iterrows():
    df["BARCODE"]=Barcode

df.to_csv('test2.csv')
```

this is an image of the input csv file

[input csv file before adding new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8DVu.png)

and here is the new csv file

[output csv file after adding new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijSq9.png)

i hope my question is clear i don't where is the trick yet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'd help the people trying to help you if you could post an example input and output DataFrame.

Comment: why do you use two `for`-loops. Do it in one `for`-loop

Comment: variable `Barcode` can keep only one value - you should create list with all values and then assign to new column.

Comment: i tried one loop same result always the result of last row in all new column

Comment: i'm not very good in python could you plz be more clear about creating list of barcode variable

Comment: you should also see [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: `Barcode = list()`and `for ...: Barcode.append(...)` and later without loop `df["BARCODE"] = Barcode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one value then you should use `list()` to keep all of them

```
Barcode = list()

for index, col in df.iterrows():
    value = TD1CodeGenerator(...)
    Barcode.append(value)

df["BARCODE"] = Barcode
```

---

You should also try [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to run function with every row without using `for`-loop

```
def func(col):
    return TD1CodeGenerator(str(col['Document type']), str(col['Country']), str(col['Document number']), str(col['Birth date']), str(col['Genre']), str(col['Expiry Date']), str(col['Nationality']), str(col['Surname']), str(col['Given name(s)']), str(col['Optional data 1']))

df["BARCODE"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: the first solution didnt work giving me error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" but using DataFrame.apply() worked like a charme thanks a lot for the help man it is really preciouse

Comment: first version should also works. You can check `print( len(df), len(Barcode) )`  to see if you have the same number of rows in list `Barcode` and in `df`